# Mutex doesn't work

Tags: c++, mutex

My code is an AVL tree and am trying to enter with `mutex`.

The `mutex` does not work. Why?

Return black screen, perhaps a deadlock.
I don't know.
Not exist recursive functions.

If I use a `lock guard` it works normally.

```
template<typename T> int avl<T>::insere (int key , T data) {

    mtx.lock();

    no * nw = new no;

    if (nw == NULL)
        return 0;

    nw->sire = NULL;
    nw->left = NULL;
    nw->right = NULL;
    nw->key = key;
    nw->data = data;

      if (tree.root == NULL) {
        tree.root = nw;
        tree.quant++;
        return 1;
    }
    no * son = tree.raiz;
    no * sire  = NULL;

    while (son != NULL) {

        sire = son;

        if (key < son->key)
            son = son->left;

        else
            son = son->right.;

    }
    nw->sire = sire;

    if (key < sire->key)
        sire->left = nw;

    else
        sire->right = nw;

    tree.quantidade++;

    no * current = nw;

    while (current != NULL) {

        int f = fator (nw);

        if (f >= 2 || f <= 2)
            balance( current);
        current = current->sire;
    }

    mtx.unlock();

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: you have multiple return statements in your function where you don't unlock your mutex. A lock_guard will do this automatically for you. If you don't use it you have to unlock the mutex before each return

Answer (score 3):

A `std::lock_guard` uses a concept which is called [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) (Resource acquisition is initialization)

RAII in short: you do an action in the constructor and do the "undo" operation in the destructor. For a Mutex this would be `unlock`

So with the `lock_guard` whenever you `return` (go out of scope) the mutex will be automatically unlocked.

When you change it to a "manual" mutex you have to make sure that you do the `unlock` on each possible exit of the function (before each `return`).

This is the reason why the RAII classes exist. So you don't have to worry about this. Whenever you change the function and add another `return` you can forget to add the `unlock`. With a `lock_guard` you don't have to think about it.

There are alternatives to this. Several `SCOPE_EXIT` makros which execute a statement the moment it leaves the scope (see `BOOST` or my more favorite `folly/ScopeGuard` for more info about this). Though they are more usefull if you don't already have a RAII class (like `lock_guard`).

There are several other examples for this in modern c++ (`shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` for example). In general you should **prefer** the RAII implementations over the manual approach to have a more robust code and less error prone.